# Jolt transform array of objects to key-value

Tags: json, jolt

> ## Problems

Hi, I'm using Jolt to transform e-commerce products data. For e.g:

```json
[
  {
    "objectID": 1,
    "string_facet": [
      {
        "facet_name": "eco_collection",
        "facet_value": "No"
      },
      {
        "facet_name": "performance_fabric",
        "facet_value": "No"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "objectID": 2,
    "string_facet": [
      {
        "facet_name": "activity",
        "facet_value": [
          "Hiking"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And my desired output is:

```json
[
    {
        "objectID": 1,
        "string_facet": {
            "eco_collection": "No",
            "performance_fabric": "No"
        }
    },
    {
        "objectID": 2,
        "string_facet": {
            "activity": [
                "Hiking"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

## What I have done so far

I have tried this spec, but it isn't what I need:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "string_facet": {
          "*": {
            "@facet_value": "[&1].string_facet.@facet_name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'm looking for an explanation in addition to solution.

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You principally need **`"@facet_value": "@facet_name"`** match, start with it, then add

- **&2** to represent going two levels up and grabbing the key name's value(`string_facet`)
- **&3** to represent going three levels up and grabbing the indices of the main array to accumulate each attributes nested within individual object of their own.

Then, add an extra **shift** transformation spec to get rid of the integer key names such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "string_facet": {
          "*": {
            "@facet_value": "&3.&2.@facet_name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]